# How to use groupBy to collect rows into a map?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

**Context**

```
sqlContext.sql(s"""
SELECT
school_name,
name,
age
FROM my_table
""")
```

**Ask**

Given the above table, I would like to group by school name and collect name, age into a `Map[String, Int]`

**For example - Pseudo-code**

```
val df = sqlContext.sql(s"""
SELECT
school_name,
age
FROM my_table
GROUP BY school_name
""")


------------------------
school_name | name  | age
------------------------
school A | "michael"| 7 
school A | "emily"  | 5
school B | "cathy"  | 10
school B | "shaun"  | 5


df.groupBy("school_name").agg(make_map)

------------------------------------
school_name | map
------------------------------------
school A    | {"michael": 7, "emily": 5}
school B    | {"cathy": 10, "shaun": 5}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Following will work with **Spark 2.0**. You can use [map](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#map(org.apache.spark.sql.Column...)) function available since 2.0 release to get columns as Map.

```
val df1 = df.groupBy(col("school_name")).agg(collect_list(map($"name",$"age")) as "map")
df1.show(false)
```

This will give you below output.

```
+-----------+------------------------------------+
|school_name|map                                 |
+-----------+------------------------------------+
|school B   |[Map(cathy -> 10), Map(shaun -> 5)] |
|school A   |[Map(michael -> 7), Map(emily -> 5)]|
+-----------+------------------------------------+
```

Now you can use `UDF` to join individual Maps into single Map like below.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val joinMap = udf { values: Seq[Map[String,Int]] => values.flatten.toMap }

val df2 = df1.withColumn("map", joinMap(col("map")))
df2.show(false)
```

This will give required output with `Map[String,Int]`.

```
+-----------+-----------------------------+
|school_name|map                          |
+-----------+-----------------------------+
|school B   |Map(cathy -> 10, shaun -> 5) |
|school A   |Map(michael -> 7, emily -> 5)|
+-----------+-----------------------------+
```

If you want to convert a column value into JSON String then **Spark 2.1.0** has introduced [to_json](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#to_json(org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) function.

```
val df3 = df2.withColumn("map",to_json(struct($"map")))
df3.show(false)
```

The `to_json` function will return following output.

```
+-----------+-------------------------------+
|school_name|map                            |
+-----------+-------------------------------+
|school B   |{"map":{"cathy":10,"shaun":5}} |
|school A   |{"map":{"michael":7,"emily":5}}|
+-----------+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: how do i do this `val df1 = df.groupBy(col("school_name")).agg(collect_list(map($"name",$"age")) as "map")
` in java?

Comment: Is this not in pyspark yet? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions

Answer (score 16):

As of spark 2.4 you can use [map_from_arrays](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#map_from_arrays) function to achieve this.

```
val df = spark.sql(s"""
    SELECT *
    FROM VALUES ('s1','a',1),('s1','b',2),('s2','a',1)
    AS (school, name, age)
""")

val df2 = df.groupBy("school").agg(map_from_arrays(collect_list($"name"), collect_list($"age")).as("map"))



+------+----+---+
|school|name|age|
+------+----+---+
|    s1|   a|  1|
|    s1|   b|  2|
|    s2|   a|  1|
+------+----+---+

+------+----------------+
|school|             map|
+------+----------------+
|    s2|        [a -> 1]|
|    s1|[a -> 1, b -> 2]|
+------+----------------+
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It achieves the correct data type of map in one shot with no UDF.

Answer (score -1):

```
df.select($"school_name",concat_ws(":",$"age",$"name").as("new_col")).groupBy($"school_name").agg(collect_set($"new_col")).show
+-----------+--------------------+                                              
|school_name|collect_set(new_col)|
+-----------+--------------------+
|   school B| [5:shaun, 10:cathy]|
|   school A|[7:michael, 5:emily]|
+-----------+--------------------+
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. If you do printSchema on the result collect_set includes an array of strings. So instead of getting a map you are simply getting strings. You can solve this by doing a UDF which would convert the array of strings to a map though.