# SQL how to "collect" rows into a single row

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have an email feature and I need to select the recipients of an email.

`users` table has columns: `id`, `full_name`

`emails` table has columns: `id`, `subject`, `body`,`sender_id`, `recipient_id`

Pseudo code is

```
SELECT
  e.id AS email_id,
  e.subject AS email_subject,
  u_sender.full_name AS sender_name,
  u_recipient.full_name AS recipient_name
FROM emails e
LEFT JOIN users u_sender
  ON e.sender_id = u_sender.id
LEFT JOIN users u_recipient
  ON e.recipient_id = u_recipient.id
```

This will return something like:

| email_id | email_subject | sender_name | recipient_name |
|     1       
|         Hello       
|       John        
|        Steve          |
|     1       
|         Hello       
|       John        
|        Mark          |
|     1       
|         Hello       
|       John        
|        Peter          |

Instead, is there a way to get something like:
| email_id | email_subject | sender_name | recipient_name |
|     1       
|         Hello       
|       John        
|   [Steve, Peter, Mark]  |

Notice that they have the same email_ids because my application can send the email to multiple recipients.

I found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41819275/how-to-use-groupby-to-collect-rows-into-a-map) but the solution is apache-exclusive.

I also found a response that uses XML PATH [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899/how-to-create-a-sql-server-function-to-join-multiple-rows-from-a-subquery-into) but it's for SQL Server 2005. I'm using postgres.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL 9 provides the [`string_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-aggregate.html) aggregation function to flatten multiple values into a single string. In your example, it would be `string_agg(u_recipient.full_name, ',')` along with a suitable `group by`:

```
select
  e.id email_id,
  e.subject email_subject,
  u_sender.full_name sender_name,
  string_agg(u_recipient.full_name, ',') recipient_name
from emails e
left join users u_sender
  on e.sender_id = u_sender.id
left join users u_recipient
  on e.recipient_id = u_recipient.id
group by email_id, email_subject, sender_name
```

Comment: An actual query would be nice :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use a GROUP BY clause with email_id, email_subject, sender_name and call STRING_AGG(recipient_name, ',')

You will have something like this:

```
SELECT email_id, email_subject, sender_name, string_agg(recipient_name, ',') FROM test GROUP BY email_id, email_subject, sender_name
```

With your query:

```
WITH X AS 
(
SELECT
  e.id AS email_id,
  e.subject AS email_subject,
  u_sender.full_name AS sender_name,
  u_recipient.full_name AS recipient_name
FROM emails e
LEFT JOIN users u_sender
  ON e.sender_id = u_sender.id
LEFT JOIN users u_recipient
  ON e.recipient_id = u_recipient.id
)
SELECT email_id, email_subject, sender_name, string_agg(recipient_name, ',') FROM X GROUP BY email_id, email_subject, sender_name;
```